# How repeat a row after a match in Python

Tags: python

I have the following data:

```
      A        B
0    27.9     1.0
1    20.6     1.0
2    10.3     1.0
3     0.0     1.0
4   349.7     1.0
5   339.4     2.0
6   329.1     1.0
7   318.9     1.0
```

And I would like every time there is a number higher than 1 in B, then the column will be duplicated by that number. The output of this data should be then:

```
       A       B
0    27.9     1.0
1    20.6     1.0
2    10.3     1.0
3     0.0     1.0
4   349.7     1.0
5   339.4     2.0
6   339.4     2.0  --> basically inserting this one here
7   329.1     1.0
8   318.9     1.0
```

I have tried with pandas but I don't seem to get it right. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [27.9, 20.6, 10.3, 0.0, 349.7, 339.4, 329.1, 318.9],
    'B': [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0]
})

for i in range(len(df)):
    if df['B'][i] > 1.0:
        # this inserts a new row between the current and previous index (i-0.5)
        df.loc[i-0.5] = [df['A'][i], df['B'][i]]

# sort and reset indexes
df = df.sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)
```

**Result**

```
       A    B
0   27.9  1.0
1   20.6  1.0
2   10.3  1.0
3    0.0  1.0
4  349.7  1.0
5  339.4  2.0 <-- inserted
6  339.4  2.0
7  329.1  1.0
8  318.9  1.0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! it seems to work, however if the number is 3 then it just repeats the row 1 times and not 2 times as it is intended.( see below)

9   298.3     1.0
10  288.0     1.0
11  277.7     3.0
12  277.7     3.0
13  270.4     1.0
14  216.0     1.0

Any thoughts on that??
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following (with Pandas, i.e. `import pandas as pd`):

```py
result = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df["B"].gt(1.0) + 1), :]
```

Result for `df`

```
       A    B
0   27.9  1.0
1   20.6  1.0
2   10.3  1.0
3    0.0  1.0
4  349.7  1.0
5  339.4  2.0
6  329.1  1.0
7  318.9  1.0
```

is

```
       A    B
0   27.9  1.0
1   20.6  1.0
2   10.3  1.0
3    0.0  1.0
4  349.7  1.0
5  339.4  2.0
5  339.4  2.0
6  329.1  1.0
7  318.9  1.0
```

If you want a fresh index use `.reset_index(drop=True)` on `result`.